# Ionic 2 http.post to login

Tags: http, post, ionic2

I'm trying to convert an ionic app in an ionic 2 app and im strugle trying to remake the login progress.
I wrote this in my ionic 2 app:

```
  loginUser(){
      localStorage.setItem('username', this.username);
      localStorage.setItem('password', this.password);
      localStorage.setItem('company', this.company);

        this.loginData = {};
        this.loginData.UserID = this.username;
        this.loginData.CompanyID = this.company;
        this.loginData.Password = this.password;


      let body = {"jsonLogin": JSON.stringify(this.loginData)}
      let link = 'working link';
      let headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      });
      let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

      this.http
          .post(link, body, options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
              data => {
              console.log(data);
               //this.navCtrl.push(MenuPage);
          }, err => {
              console.log(err);
          });
   }
```

While in the ionic 1 app this was the code:

```
$scope.loginUser = function () {
        json = {};
        json.UserID = $scope.data.username;
        json.CompanyID = $scope.data.company;
        json.Password = $scope.data.password;

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                "jsonLogin": JSON.stringify(json)
            },
            url: 'working link',
            transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
        }
```

My problem is in the POST, when I post with my code of the ionic 2 app this is what my Form Data looks like:

```
{
"jsonLogin": "{\"UserID\":\"admin\",\"CompanyID\":\"test\",\"Password\":\"pass\"}"
}:
```

While the ionic 1 app Form Data looks like this:

```
jsonLogin:{"UserID":"admin","CompanyID":"test","Password":"pass"}
```

The POST is working since I got an error message from server, I just don't know how I can format the data to do a correct POST.

Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT:**
Got it working by added a new header:

```
let headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': '*/*'
      });
```

And send a hardcoded string:

```
createStringForLogin(username: any, company: any, password: any){
         return 'jsonLogin={"UserID":"'+username+'","CompanyID":"'+company+'","Password":"'+password+'"}';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
let body = {"jsonLogin": this.loginData};
```

should solve your problem. Let me know if it does not work.

Also, if you are having trouble in setting parameters to `this.loginData`. Set them like this:

```
this.loginData = {};
this.loginData['UserID'] = this.username;
this.loginData['CompanyID'] = this.company;
this.loginData['Password'] = this.password;
```

Comment: I think it worked right? Json is formatted according to your requirements. Now, how you send it to server is upto you. If not what is the problem now? Also, I am not correcting any post behaviour here. If there is some problem in post request and parameters then you need to correct it.

Comment: My problem is getting the POST the way it have to be... I'm not the owner of the ionic 1 app, I just got the work to convert it to the ionic 2 so I don't know what server expects for login, I just know if the POST go as the same as the ionic 1 app that it will work...
And as you can see in the question above, I just wanted the output to be in one line like this "jsonLogin:{"UserID":"admin","CompanyID":"test","Password":"pass"}"

Comment: Ok. From my knowledge, body is a json object. In my app sending it like this works. You need to test the post parameters from ionic 1 app and ionic 2 app. You can do this from browser => Inspect Element => Network and the particular post that is happening. In it's request payload's section you will see the data params. Compare both and see. Also, in error section, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, I got status 200 Ok, the problem is that I don't really know what server want to receive... So I'm just trying to give me the same input as the ionic 1 app did, right know it just don't accept what I send and he return me a null user

Comment: Then you need to inspect the post request on both apps. And figure out the difference in each and every post request parameter in headers on both. 1 way to check if the post request really works is install some REST client on browser and try doing post from that. For chrome I can suggest ARC.

Comment: Using the ARC, I notice that when I added another header (Accept: */*), http://imgur.com/OgBiAwI , and I got the user, so it worked, but I can't send the same input to the server by code... When I use the post the data just mess up

Comment: Ok, Got it working, thank you for the help with the ARC client.